# Understanding existential types in Scala

Tags: scala, existential-type

Considering following code

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Set
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

// classes to create field types that do conversion of string to other types

trait Field[A] {
    def convert(x: String): A // Need to define convert for the trait, too.
}

case class IntField extends Field[Int] {
    override def convert(x: String): Int = x.toInt
}

case class StringField extends Field[String] {
    override def convert(x: String): String = x
}

// this function can take any Field type and return a HashMap, 
// more important here is type of key not the value of HashMap
// which has to match with value returned from Field.convert()

def someFunc[A](field: Field[A]): HashMap[A, Int] = {
    val index = new HashMap[A, Int]()
    val data = List("111", "222", "333")

    for (line <- data) {
        val values: A = field.convert(line)
        index.put(values, 0)
    }
    index
}

// this empty set will be populated with Field objects, and here I get an error
var fields = Set[Field[A]]()

def addField[A](field: Field[A]): Unit = fields += field

addField(StringField())
addField(IntField())

for (field <- fields) println(someFunc(field))

// RESULT
Map(333 -> 0, 222 -> 0, 111 -> 0) // HashMap[String, Int]
Map(111 -> 0, 333 -> 0, 222 -> 0) // HashMap[Int, Int]
```

Above will not compile, the error is `not found: type A` when creating `var fields` - . Now when I change this line to read:

`var fields = Set[Field[A] forSome {type A}]()`

Everything compiles but I don't exactly understand what happens here. I understand that when executing `var fields = Set[Field[A]]()` type A doesn't exist but how is other line fixing this issue and is it even proper solution or it just happens to work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

`Field[A] forSome {type A}`- you can use A as a Type (parametrize Field with type  A) because you declare this type in curly brackets, existential types are a way to say that you can accept any type, in your case when method addField is parametrize, using Seq[Field] with existential type is a one of solutions because this collection will store different types.

Comment: If I simply declare `type A` at the top of the code and use `var fields = Set[Field[A]]()` it will still not compile. Is it because `Field[A] forSome {type A}` creates `type A` in the context of `Field[A]`? If that makes sense.

Comment: If you declare type like this: type A = Field[B] forSome {type B} it will compile, so A  forSome {type A} is just special scala construct which enable you to create existential types, which are the way to say that it can be any type

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might not really by with existential types but rather with definition and usage of generic types as `var fields = A` would not compile either.

In

```
var fields = Set[Field[A]]()
```

`A` is undefined because you have not declared it anywhere within the scope.

in

```
trait Field[A] {

def someFunc[A](field: Field[A]): HashMap[A, Int] = {

def addField[A](field: Field[A]): Unit = fields += field
```

A is declared as type parameter, that is it will be defined by usage.

As you put both `StringField` and `IntField` in your `fields` var, I guess you want fields to be a `Set` of any kind `Field`. So usually you tell the compiler that by a wildcard:

```
var fields = Set[Field[_]]()
```

which is essentially the short way of writing

```
var fields = Set[Field[A] forSome {type A}]()
```